# Changing Schema Name to higher environments

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a schema in my development environment in Oracle database.

In my dev env my schema name is say prabhu_order. So when I'm getting ddl to promote upper environment it is coming as prabhu_order.table1,prabhu_order.table2..., etc

In all of my higher environments it is just ORDER.

Now I'm doing ctrl replace to change the schema name. I'm afraid to do that when I have 50 ddls...

Please suugest me a way to change schema name!

Comment: How are you getting the DDL, with dbms_metadata?

Comment: Yes using metadata.get_DDL

Comment: `replace('prabhu_order.', 'order.')`?

Comment: Any other way other than replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben's suggestion to use `replace` seems pretty sensible, but if you don't want to do that for some reason you can do it programatically - it's just rather more work and more code.

Since you're using the `dbms_metadata` package to extract the DDL you can use the [set_remap_param](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026) procedure to modify how the DDL is presented; but it isn't as simple to use for an ad hoc query as `set_transform_param` as it doesn't seem to work with the default session handle. One of the options is `REMAP_SCHEMA`, so you can change the schema as you extract the DDL, much like with data pump.

If I create a dummy table, set some simple transforms at session level, and then call `get_ddl` I get:

```
create table t42(id number);

begin
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(
    transform_handle => DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    name => 'PRETTY', value => FALSE);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(
    transform_handle => DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    name => 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', value => FALSE);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(
    transform_handle => DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    name => 'STORAGE', value => FALSE);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(
    transform_handle => DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    name => 'SQLTERMINATOR', value => TRUE);
end;
/

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'T42') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','T42')                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "STACKOVERFLOW"."T42" ("ID" NUMBER) ;
```

Which obviously has my schema, `STACKOVERFLOW`. With a PL/SQL block I can remap that to order, and I'm using an SQL*Plus `VARIABLE` to retrieve and display the text:

```
variable c clob

declare
  l_handle number;
  l_transform_handle number;
begin
  l_handle := dbms_metadata.open(object_type => 'TABLE');

  -- identify the object you want
  dbms_metadata.set_filter(l_handle, 'SCHEMA', USER);
  dbms_metadata.set_filter(l_handle, 'NAME', 'T42');

  -- set up a MODIFY transform and apply REMAP_SCHEMA to it
  l_transform_handle := dbms_metadata.add_transform(handle => l_handle,
    name => 'MODIFY');
  dbms_metadata.set_remap_param(transform_handle => l_transform_handle,
    name => 'REMAP_SCHEMA', old_value => USER, new_value => 'ORDER');
  -- switch back from XML to DDL
  l_transform_handle := dbms_metadata.add_transform(l_handle, 'DDL');

  -- set other 'pretty' transforms, to taste
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(transform_handle => l_transform_handle,
    name => 'PRETTY', value => FALSE);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(transform_handle => l_transform_handle,
    name => 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', value => FALSE);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(transform_handle => l_transform_handle,
    name => 'STORAGE', value => FALSE);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(transform_handle => l_transform_handle,
    name => 'SQLTERMINATOR', value => TRUE);

  :c := dbms_metadata.fetch_clob(handle => l_handle);
  dbms_metadata.close(l_handle);
end;
/
```

So now the `c` variable holds the DDL:

```
print c

C
---------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "ORDER"."T42" ("ID" NUMBER) ;
```

Rather than using an anonymous block and an SQL*Plus variable, you could turn that into a function that takes the object type and object name and returns the DDL as a CLOB.

You might prefer to not have the schema specified at all, which would be more useful if this is then going to be put into source control, or might be used in other environments. To do that just pass null as the new schema instead:

```
  dbms_metadata.set_remap_param(transform_handle => l_transform_handle,
    name => 'REMAP_SCHEMA', old_value => USER, new_value => null);

C
-------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "T42" ("ID" NUMBER) ;
```

Comment: [This discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1008491) might be where I'd seen this approach before. And also shows a function version.

Comment: Many Thanks, Alex!! Agreed with Bob on replace but I was facing some issue with that. Well This is bit lengthy however no risk i feel.. Yet again thanks. Stakeoverflow is indeed a platform to learn and grow..Keep up the good work :-)